# PHP Query taking a while to return results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am running the below MySQL Query in PHP on my web server, the database is located on a separate server:

```
$sql="select * from call_history where extension_number = '0536*500' and flow = 'in' and DATE(initiated) = '".date("Y-m-d")."' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn);
echo mysql_num_rows($rs).' Calls IN';
```

the `call_history` table has thousands of rows in, is there any way to speed up the query?

*Please note: I only have read only access to the database*

Comment: We'd probably have to see the db schema to know for sure. Without write access you can't add indeces to `extension_number` or `flow` or `initiated` which would speed things up considerably.

Comment: [The mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: Why not just `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: i just changed all my queries to be select COUNT(id) as counter but still takes a while to load

Comment: Have you checked whether it runs any faster when running it directly against the database using phpmyadmin or another tool? You most likely need to have that table indexed on the columns you're searching on.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not installed on the server

Answer (score 0):

```
$initiated = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as n FROM `call_history` where extension_number = '0536*500' and flow = 'in' and DATE(initiated) =\"{$initiated}\"";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$pbx01_conn);
$rs = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
echo $rs['n'] . ' Calls IN';
```

You can also optimize your tables through phpMyAdmin: Tables -> Operations Tab -> Table Maintenance Section -> Optimize Table

Comment: this still seems to take a while

Comment: mysql_query("OPTIMIZE TABLE `callhistory`");

Answer (score 0):

Add indexes to the search columns `extension_number`, `flow` and `initiated`.

MySQL is observable slower on searching among several thousands records if there are no indexes.